# How can I efficiently call api that returns 2+ million data, save the data locally and show to user on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on an app that works offline, when the app starts for the first time i need to call api to load some large data, process it and save locally.

My first approach was to load all the data at once, but doing this, returns upstream request timeout error as the data are just too large.

current approach i am using is to make the api call with limit to the number of data i get, process it and show to user.

Now what is the best approach to get the remaining data? i don't want to use pagination as i have a search feature in the app.

If you have any better alternative way to handle this do suggest please.

Comment: It is never a good idea to fetch such a large amount of data altogether. Pagination is the best possible way to handle large amount of data. Just use search function on your api and return result.

Comment: as i said we can't use pagination as the app works offline and we have a search function on the app where user can search for data using the locally saved data. if we don't have offline mode and search feature, then yes definitely i will use pagination... I think telegram is doing what i am trying to achieve.. it load some data and the rest is called in background

Comment: So in your current approach how are you limiting the number of data you are getting?

Comment: oh yes for that i am using a key to indicate the limit of data i want, i thot u meant pagination when scroll to bottom of list to load more data.

here is the scenario, example: if total message is 500, i call the api to get 100 message and show to user, now i'm looking for a better approach to call and get the remaining 400 messages, without stoping user from using the app and without implementation scroll to load more